# Unity - paiting terrain details vs combining a large mesh

Tags: unity, performance

I am about to start making my landscape, and am using a low poly style.

I think I'd prefer not to use the terrain system and instead just use a bunch of meshes, since all my grass/flowers are 3d models.

Does anyone know how this will effect performance, keeping in mind that Ill combine all my vegetation to one large mesh when Im done, so that it's not hundreds of gameobjects. Is it a lot worse than using the terrain tool with detail painting?

Comment: We don't know the rendering performance of your meshes. The best way for you to find out is to make a quick test - even if you don't have all your assets finished yet, grab the ones you've got and duplicate them up to about the final density you expect. Then profile the resulting scene. If the performance is within your target range, you're good to go.If it's too costly, you can post here with samples of the look you want and details of your profiling to ask for ways to achieve a similar look more efficiently.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks! Ill do that :)